# Defining Subscription IDs for cloud kit remote push notifications

Tags: cloudkit, subscription

I have about 12 CKRecord entities and assuming I store information in both public and private databases and also share from private database, I have to define at least 3 subscription IDs one for each CKRecord which means 36 subscription IDs. I can do this in individual controllers and in each controller I can handle remote push notifications recevied form AppDelegate.

In another method I can define 3 subscriptions one for each type of database and when the push notification arrives, for each zone, peek inside each record and based on each record type handle subscription. Does all this code need to be defined in AppDelegate?

Which is the better method and what are the advantages disadvantages of each. I would like to know before I spend time lot of time picking on one method  and then having to backtrack because it was not right? Or do I need both methods to serve different purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically use the second method you mention. I use the CloudKit `subscription ID` to determine which method I should call from the **AppDelegate** and then have code elsewhere that processes the notification appropriately.

Something like this:

```
//MARK: Background & Push Notifications
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
  
  let dict = userInfo as! [String: NSObject]
  
  if let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: dict), let subscriptionID = notification.subscriptionID{
    print("iOS Notification: \(subscriptionID)")
    switch subscriptionID{
      case "a":
        processNotificationA(notification: notification)
      case "b":
        processNotificationB(notification: notification)
      default:
        processAnyNotification(notification: notification)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So processNotificationA can be for public DB, processNotificationB for private DB and processAnyNotification for shared DB. In each processNotificaiton, I can step through CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation for zone changes fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock for record changes, captuer (1) added records, (2) deleted records (3) changed record IDs. But ten I have to check for each entity subscription as necessary. Can all this be completed in AppDelegate and then respective controllers pull each list of appropriate records IDs? Would this describe a high level flow. Can you please comment?

Comment: Yeah, you could embed the logic in your `subscriptionID` and then route things from within `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. For example, your `subscriptionID` could be something like: `public-recordTypeA`, `private-recordTypeB`, etc. Then you can parse the `subscriptionID` to know how to route the `CKNotification`.